# How to avoid empty set in pandas's concate and to_csv function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary to be stored in csv through pandas:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(node_dict[k], name=k) for k in HEADERS], 1)
df.to_csv(os.path.join(abspath, outputfile), sep='\t', index=False)
```

The keys correspond to the columns in the CSV or pandas frame, and the values are a list of sets. Each set is the current row's values. Let's see if I have two columns:

```
   names                     companies                      
{'john', 'smith', 'mary'}   {'ms', 'fb'} 
 set()                      {'ms', 'fb', 'tw', 'g', 'lk'}
 ...                         ...
```

Some rows's values are empty, as indicated by the set() printout in the file. I hope there is a way to modify this line:

```
[pd.Series(node_dict[k], name=k) for k in HEADERS]
```

to write the invisible '' into the file, instead of the string 'set()'.

Sample of the dict:

```
node_dict['names'] = [{'john', 'smith', 'mary'}, {}]
node_dict['companies'] = [{'ms', 'fb'}, {'ms', 'fb', 'tw', 'g', 'lk'} ]
```

Of course the actual lists are much longer in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dictionary?

Comment: @DarioHett, please see the dict.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like:

`node_dict = {k: [x if x else "invisible" for x in v] for k,v in node_dict.items()}`

prior to doing `[pd.Series(node_dict[k], name=k) for k in HEADERS]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop all the `{}`. Convert the `dict` to a `string`, drop and re-evaluate as dictionary. Done.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(eval(str(node_dict[k]).replace('{}',' ')), name=k) for k in HEADERS], 1)
```

```
df
                 names            companies
0  {john, mary, smith}             {fb, ms}
1                  NaN  {g, ms, lk, fb, tw}
```

Even works with trailing `,` in the dictionary. `df.to_csv()` evaluates the NaN automatically as empty string `DataFrame.to_csv(path, sep: str = ',', na_rep: str = ''...)`